# Gem versioning: difference between syntax?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

Whats the difference between the following two syntaxes for including a gem into a rails app?

`gem 'apartment', '~> 1.0', '>= 1.0.2'`

vs

`gem 'apartment', '~> 1.0'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line says "any 1.0 version":

```
gem 'apartment', '~> 1.0'
```

This line says "any 1.0 version at least 1.0.2"

```
gem 'apartment', '~> 1.0', '>= 1.0.2'
```

Neither should allow version 2.0 or higher.

Answer (score 1):

The specifier `~>` has a special meaning, best shown by example.

```
~> 2.0.3
```

is identical to

```
>= 2.0.3 and < 2.1
```

---

```
~> 2.1
```

is identical to

```
>= 2.1 and < 3.0
```

---

`~> 2.2.beta` will match prerelease versions like 2.2.beta.12.

*taken from the great [Bundler.io](http://bundler.io/v1.5/gemfile.html)